# Disable Kafka and Micrometer in Apache Camel tests using Quarkus?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, quarkus, micrometer

We are using Quarkus 2.11.3.Final along with `camel-quarkus-micrometer`, plus `quarkus-micrometer-registry-prometheus` and `camel-quarkus-microprofile-health`. The problem is that when we run the tests, the following exceptions are thrown:

```bash
2023-04-17 18:45:33,275 WARN  [org.apa.cam.sup.EventHelper] (main) Error notifying event 9C0D3FDCA14EBDA-0000000000000000 exchange completed. This exception will be ignored.: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.camel.Endpoint.getEndpointUri()" because "endpoint" is null
        at org.apache.camel.component.micrometer.eventnotifier.MicrometerExchangeEventNotifierNamingStrategy.getTags(MicrometerExchangeEventNotifierNamingStrategy.java:53)
        at org.apache.camel.component.micrometer.eventnotifier.MicrometerExchangeEventNotifier.handleDoneEvent(MicrometerExchangeEventNotifier.java:104)
        at org.apache.camel.component.micrometer.eventnotifier.MicrometerExchangeEventNotifier.notify(MicrometerExchangeEventNotifier.java:75)
        at org.apache.camel.support.EventHelper.doNotifyEvent(EventHelper.java:1351)

(...)
```

Also, I see that Quarkus attempts to connect to the Kafka instance, so I ended up having to set up the Kafka devservice so at least we didn't have to see any error messages related to that.

Is there any way we can disable those? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable Kafka devservices you can add configuration to `application.properties`:

```
quarkus.kafka.devservices.enabled=false
```

To disable Micrometer for testing add:

```
%test.quarkus.micrometer.enabled=false
```

Or if you want more fine grained control over Camel Micrometer, there are some additional configuration options to enable / disable specific features:

https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/3.0.x/reference/extensions/micrometer.html#extensions-micrometer-additional-camel-quarkus-configuration

Comment: Thank you! Disabling micrometer did help reducing the amount of messages thrown while testing!

However, if I don't set the `quarkus.kafka.devservices.enabled` and the `quarkus.kafka.devservices.port` then I get a `Connection to node ... could not be established. Broker may not be available.` messages, even though the tests continue. If I set `enabled.false`, then I get `ConfigurationExceptions` because it `Failed to load config value of type class ... for kafka.bootstrap.servers`. Does this mean that we need Kafka yes or yes? Thank you!

Comment: It depends what your app is doing & what you are testing. If there's something that expects a Kafka broker to be available (like the camel-kafka component), then you'll need to provide it either through devservices, set it up yourself, or disable whatever functionality is using Kafka. E.g you could disable a camel RouteBuilder class that uses Kafka with configuration property `%test.quarkus.camel.routes-discovery.exclude-patterns`.

Comment: Crystal clear! Thank you very much for the help!